# Periodicity of product of two orthogonal sinusoidal functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am looking for a rule to find the time period $T$ for the following function:
$$f(t) = A_1sin(\omega_1t+\phi_1) \cdot A_2sin(\omega_2t+\phi_2)$$
with $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$ and $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2} \in \mathbb{N}$.

If there is no such explicit rule, does maybe a rule of thumb exist?

I tried $T = \frac{2\pi}{\lvert \omega_1-\omega_2\rvert}$ as well as $T = \frac{2\pi} {min(\omega_1,\omega_2)}$ but both seem wrong.

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: I don't have time to work this out but here's how I'd start. Begin with $\phi_1=\phi_2=0$ for simplicity and try some simple examples of $\omega_1,\omega_2$. (You can probably wlog assume $\omega_2 = 1$ and $\omega_1 \in \mathbb{N}$.)